# Event handler doesn't execute after subscribing new event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling

I have a MVVM application in WPF.  I have an event that gets dispatched from a static instance of a class.

When a given condition occurs, I need to listen for the next occurrence of said event. I do this with the following code:

```
myInstance.OnData += myEventHandlerInstance;
```

The event handler is removed at a later time, but as soon as it is added, the event handlers in the other view models no longer execute.  I have verified that the dispatcher is the same instance in all places where the event is fired and handled (using the methods described below).

Why does the existing handler not get executed?

Comment: Just to be clear are you hooking the event only under certain circumstances/conditions? If so you'd have to ensure that all event subscription and un-subscription match; you could create a method "Subscribe" taking a bool argument to achieve this. The handled flag is available for only RoutedEvents going up the visual tree, not regular events as shown in your code snippet.

Comment: Are you updating UI within the handler, when OnData fires?

Comment: No, I don't update the UI within this particular handler.

Comment: To elaborate, a OnData event is raised anytime there is data.  If the data is a specific type, a specific event is also dispatched.  It is inside the more specific event where properties bound to views are updated.  There can only be one request for data pending at a given time, so the idea is to wait for the data to come back then perform the desired request.

Comment: Have you considered ensuring that when the event(s) are fired are executed on the same thread/dispatcher?

Comment: that's an excellent question and I was wondering if threading issues could be at play here.  I am not creating any new threads, so shouldn't there only be two threads here?  The UI thread and the application thread?

Comment: Yes, but given that you are updating the properties bound to the views, the event handlers would have to execute on the UI thread. Am assuming, if they get fired from the application thread, it is likely that at some instances the event handlers may execute on the application thread. So you need to ensure that your code gets invoked on the correct thread

Comment: Looks like it's the same instance of the dispatcher.  They are equal when using the equality operator and their Hash Codes are the same.

Comment: I am not sure whether that equality check would work; I think the best way to check would be to call CheckAccess() on the Dispatcher as in my suggested solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone.  You helped me focus in on the problem.  The problem was purely a structure/logic issue, I was able to dig deeper into the code.

Answer (score 0):

delete this line:

```
myInstance.OnData -= new EventHandler(myInstance_onData);
```

Why were you doing this? You should get the original event handler and remove that. Also, you should do this outside the event handler itself.

Comment: The event is listened to in a number of different places. I need to create a one-shot event, thus the need to remove the event.

Comment: Just for yuks, I created an instance level version of the event handler in the ctor and add and remove that, still getting the same behavior though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put in something like this, to ensure that your code is executing on the right thread:

```
if(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
   <Code here>
}
else
{
   Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(<Code here>)
}
```

Comment: I think exceptions would be thrown if this were the problem.

Comment: I tried this but the else block is never hit so I don't think this is the cause of the problem